# Copying 'this' pointer

Tags: c++

Got very weird problem...

I have variable:

```
Application *ApplicationHandle = NULL;
```

in Application's function I do:

```
ApplicationHandle = this;
```

And `ApplicationHandle` still remains as `NULL`... i'm checking this with debugger, before this operation `ApplicationHandle` is `NULL`, and 'this' got some address, I can see variables of this class that are valid. After operation `ApplicationHandle` should be the same pointer as `this`, but it is still `NULL`.

How is that possible?

Comment: Do you have a local and global variable with a same name (ApplicationHandle)? Do have a piece of code that resets the value back to NULL again? Share a piece of code with us...

Comment: Don't have any local pointer to my class, only got that global.

Comment: You're gonna have to paste some code.

Comment: For the record, the following works fine: http://pastebin.com/h3gYiqaQ

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QfLrF70u 
Here is the code. Also CreateWindow doesn't create hWnd, i've read the reason is that WndProc is not working, and that's it... my program doesn't 'reach' WndProc.

Comment: Don't define a static variable inside a header - it will make one copy for every compiled source file, leading to behaviors like the one you're experiencing.

Comment: That's it, Synxis! Funny, because i've got similar example with static defined in header and it works... Whatever, big thanks, it works!

Comment: @user1764961: If it included the information with the static variable, it would make you learn something. As is, it doesn't (unless you happen to read the comments, the comment with the pastebin link happens to be still there, you happen to follow it, and the link happens to still work).

Comment: @celtschk is correct. The question, in this case, is lacking critical information and thus needs work. Being able to guess the answer might be relevant trivia for an interview, but that still does not make it a good question and is not what the voting is for.

Comment: Guys, you are 100% right... lack of 'static' word in my question is caused by my 'experiments' with code to get this code working... I have never used static variables before and had no idea it really matters... anyway, big thanks, now I have read about static and get some knowledge... mistakes are the best teachers ^^,

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving the static variable out of the global namespace and into the class as a static class member.  Here is an example:

```
// test.hpp

#ifndef TEST_HPP
#define TEST_HPP

class Test
{
public:
    // Constructor: Assign this to TestPointer
    Test(void) { TestPointer = this; }

    // This is just a definition
    static Test* TestPointer;

private:
    unsigned m_unNormalMemberVariable;
};

#endif /* #ifndef TEST_HPP */
```

The above code will not work by itself, you need to declare the actual memory of the static member variable (just like you would for a member function).

```
// test.cpp

#include "test.hpp"

#include <iostream>

// The actual pointer is declared here
Test* Test::TestPointer = NULL;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Test myTest;

    std::cout << "Created Test Instance" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "myTest Pointer:  " << &myTest << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Static Member:   " << Test::TestPointer << std::endl;

    Test myTest2;

    std::cout << "Created Second Test Instance" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "myTest2 Pointer: " << &myTest2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Static Member:   " << Test::TestPointer << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The static member can be access from any file, not just the file containing the line `Test* Test::TestPointer = NULL;`.  To access the contents of the static pointer, use `Test::TestPointer`.